# Problems while importing an excel file

Tags: python, pandas

Hey coding community!

I am absolutely new to coding!

I simply want to import an excel file to Python(3.8) via Sublime Text(3.2.2) in order to have Python randomly select a cell from a specific column. I've installed pandas module (correct me if it's not a module) and using some tutorial began to import the excel file,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'location of the file.xlsx')
print(df)
```

but came across an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a package

Let me know what am I doing wrong? More than happy to provide more context in order to figure out where I messed up.

Longer error:

[image]

After adding the sys.path

[image]

Comment: Is this the full code that is generating the error? Or where does urllib come into play?

Comment: Those three lines I provided is all I have on my SublimeText... Although the error message is much longer:

Comment: Yeah I could use the longer error!